# how to extend model of gem file in our ror app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> spree/core/app/models/spree/product.rb

This is file that is stored in my gem file. I want to add some functionality to model file, so how to extend gem file in my app.

Comment: Create a file with same hierarchy `spree/core/app/models/spree/product.rb` under `lib`. This file will override gem's model file

Comment: but when apply this changes then it creates problems like other functionality does not work well. Any way to extend this model like class has _eval do.

Comment: You can either subclass it or use `class.eval_do`

Answer (score 1):

You can use decorators. Create a `product_decorator.rb` in `app/models/spree`

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do

  #Place your functionality here
  def some_action
    ...
  end

end
```

Refer this [document](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html). A simple google could have got you this document.

Comment: when i added this functionality then it show error in browser like "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Spree::Product"                                                               Spree::Product.class_eval do


   def self.to_csv
      CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |pro|
        csv << pro.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
    end

end

Comment: What path have you added the file? is it in `app/models/spree`?